# How to grant roles usage on security integrations Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to grant usage on a security integration I have created.

```
GRANT USAGE ON INTEGRATION <integration_name> TO ROLE test_role;
```

This should be the query that would grant usage, and it runs without error (*'Statement executed successfully.'*). But it doesn't do anything, I can't get any details on the security integration.

```
DESC SECURITY INTEGRATION <integration_name>
```

This is what I would like to run with the test_role, but it still says *'SQL access control error: Insufficient privileges to operate on integration '<integration_name>'*.

Is it just not possbile to grant usage on a security integration?

Comment: Have you flushed privileges?

Comment: No, I haven't heard of this before. I also can't find any Snowflake documentation on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I see, only the owner of the security integration object can use DESCRIBE command on the object. You may change the ownership and test it:

```
USE ROLE accountadmin;

grant ownership on INTEGRATION test_integration to role test_role REVOKE CURRENT GRANTS;

USE ROLE test_role;

DESC SECURITY INTEGRATION test_integration;
```

Comment: So if I understand correctly, only 1 role at a time can describe a security integration? So if I want test_role to be able to describe security integration, Accountadmin won't be able to describe security integration anymore? Because test_role would be the new owner and ownership would be revoked from accountadmin?

Comment: Yes, unless they change the ownership. It is probably related with the security concerns on the integration objects.

Comment: @Selin: If you've setup a proper [role hierarchy](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-access-control-overview#role-hierarchy-and-privilege-inheritance) (where every role is ultimately granted to ACCOUNTADMIN at the top of the food chain), then ACCOUNTADMIN will remain able to describe the security integration.

For example, we grant ownership to SECURITYADMIN, and it works like a charm.